# Capture if any process in pipeline exits with non-zero

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I have this code:

```
   ql_timeout=2500 ql_write_and_keep_open | nc localhost "${ql_server_port}" | while read response; do
         echo "response from server: $response";
         if [[ "$response" == "released" ]]; then
            echo "quicklock: Lock was released.";
            return 0;
         fi
   done || {
       >&2 echo "quicklock: could not release lock.";
       return 1;
    }
```

what is happening is that the first proc `ql_write_and_keep_open` will timeout and the pipeline will close.

If any of the processes exit with non-zero I guess I would like to capture that, is there a way to do that?

I am also no sure if using:

```
done || { ... };
```

is the correct syntax either. I do know though, that the `while read` process is happening in a subshell.

Comment: Yeah I think this answer has this one covered: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These answers are really good:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another

I think this is basically what I want to do:

```
(
   set -o pipefail;

   ql_node_value="$json" ql_to=2500 ql_write_and_keep_open | nc localhost "${ql_server_port}" | while read response; do
     echo "response from server: $response";
     return 0;
     if [[ "$response" == "released" ]]; then
        echo "quicklock: Lock was released.";
        return 0;
     fi
   done;
 )

 exit_code=$?

 if [[ ${exit_code} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "quicklock: lock was released!";
 fi

 echo "quicklock: could not release lock."  >&2 ;
 return 1;
```